# Is MAUI Label for TextType as Html using an XML parser on Windows?

Tags: .net-core, maui, maui-windows

The documentation for the MAUI `Label` control and its `TextType` property says about the type `Html` support in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/label?view=net-maui-7.0:

> Displaying HTML in a Label is limited to the HTML tags that are
> supported by the underlying platform.

It doesn't tell what is supposed to happen if some "tags" are not supported on a platform. I see a crash of the complete MAUI application under Windows with some (as I would think) harmless `p` "tags" i.e. the following crashes for me on Windows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="MauiLabelTextTypeHtmlTests.MainPage">

    <ScrollView>
        <VerticalStackLayout
            Spacing="25"
            Padding="30,0"
            VerticalOptions="Center">

            <Label TextType="Html"><![CDATA[<p>This is paragraph 1.<p>This is paragraph 2.]]></Label>

        </VerticalStackLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</ContentPage>
```

Is a crash the expected result if the `Label` control can't handle the HTML "tags"?

Why does it crash?

The remaining output console lines show a loading of `XDocument`, is the `Label` control on Windows trying to parse HTML "tags" as well-formed XML and crashes off if the HTML tags do not obey XML well-formedness rules?

The sample renders fine as two lines/paragraphs of text with MAUI under Android.

A sample output in the debug output pane for a run with above sample markup (the app window never shows up at all) is e.g.

```
'MauiLabelTextTypeHtmlTests.exe' (CoreCLR: DefaultDomain): Loaded 'C:\Users\marti\Source\Repos\martin-honnen\MauiLabelTextTypeHtmlTests\bin\Debug\net7.0-windows10.0.19041.0\win10-x64\AppX\System.Private.CoreLib.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'MauiLabelTextTypeHtmlTests.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Users\marti\Source\Repos\martin-honnen\MauiLabelTextTypeHtmlTests\bin\Debug\net7.0-windows10.0.19041.0\win10-x64\AppX\MauiLabelTextTypeHtmlTests.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'MauiLabelTextTypeHtmlTests.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Users\marti\Source\Repos\martin-honnen\MauiLabelTextTypeHtmlTests\bin\Debug\net7.0-windows10.0.19041.0\win10-x64\AppX\System.Runtime.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'MauiLabelTextTypeHtmlTests.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Users\marti\Source\Repos\martin-honnen\MauiLabelTextTypeHtmlTests\bin\Debug\net7.0-windows10.0.19041.0\win10-x64\AppX\WinRT.Runtime.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'MauiLabelTextTypeHtmlTests.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Users\marti\Source\Repos\martin-honnen\MauiLabelTextTypeHtmlTests\bin\Debug\net7.0-windows10.0.19041.0\win10-x64\AppX\System.Runtime.InteropServices.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'MauiLabelTextTypeHtmlTests.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Users\marti\Source\Repos\martin-honnen\MauiLabelTextTypeHtmlTests\bin\Debug\net7.0-windows10.0.19041.0\win10-x64\AppX\System.Collections.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'MauiLabelTextTypeHtmlTests.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Users\marti\Source\Repos\martin-honnen\MauiLabelTextTypeHtmlTests\bin\Debug\net7.0-windows10.0.19041.0\win10-x64\AppX\System.Collections.Concurrent.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'MauiLabelTextTypeHtmlTests.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Users\marti\Source\Repos\martin-honnen\MauiLabelTextTypeHtmlTests\bin\Debug\net7.0-windows10.0.19041.0\win10-x64\AppX\System.Threading.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'MauiLabelTextTypeHtmlTests.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Users\marti\Source\Repos\martin-honnen\MauiLabelTextTypeHtmlTests\bin\Debug\net7.0-windows10.0.19041.0\win10-x64\AppX\Microsoft.WinUI.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'MauiLabelTextTypeHtmlTests.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Users\marti\Source\Repos\martin-honnen\MauiLabelTextTypeHtmlTests\bin\Debug\net7.0-windows10.0.19041.0\win10-x64\AppX\System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'MauiLabelTextTypeHtmlTests.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Users\marti\Source\Repos\martin-honnen\MauiLabelTextTypeHtmlTests\bin\Debug\net7.0-windows10.0.19041.0\win10-x64\AppX\System.Private.Uri.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'MauiLabelTextTypeHtmlTests.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Users\marti\Source\Repos\martin-honnen\MauiLabelTextTypeHtmlTests\bin\Debug\net7.0-windows10.0.19041.0\win10-x64\AppX\System.ObjectModel.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'MauiLabelTextTypeHtmlTests.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Users\marti\Source\Repos\martin-honnen\MauiLabelTextTypeHtmlTests\bin\Debug\net7.0-windows10.0.19041.0\win10-x64\AppX\System.ComponentModel.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'MauiLabelTextTypeHtmlTests.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Users\marti\Source\Repos\martin-honnen\MauiLabelTextTypeHtmlTests\bin\Debug\net7.0-windows10.0.19041.0\win10-x64\AppX\System.Numerics.Vectors.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'MauiLabelTextTypeHtmlTests.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Users\marti\Source\Repos\martin-honnen\MauiLabelTextTypeHtmlTests\bin\Debug\net7.0-windows10.0.19041.0\win10-x64\AppX\Microsoft.Windows.SDK.NET.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'MauiLabelTextTypeHtmlTests.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Users\marti\Source\Repos\martin-honnen\MauiLabelTextTypeHtmlTests\bin\Debug\net7.0-windows10.0.19041.0\win10-x64\AppX\System.Security.Cryptography.Algorithms.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'MauiLabelTextTypeHtmlTests.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Users\marti\Source\Repos\martin-honnen\MauiLabelTextTypeHtmlTests\bin\Debug\net7.0-windows10.0.19041.0\win10-x64\AppX\System.Security.Cryptography.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'MauiLabelTextTypeHtmlTests.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Users\marti\Source\Repos\martin-honnen\MauiLabelTextTypeHtmlTests\bin\Debug\net7.0-windows10.0.19041.0\win10-x64\AppX\System.Security.Cryptography.Csp.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'MauiLabelTextTypeHtmlTests.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Users\marti\Source\Repos\martin-honnen\MauiLabelTextTypeHtmlTests\bin\Debug\net7.0-windows10.0.19041.0\win10-x64\AppX\System.Security.Cryptography.Primitives.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'MauiLabelTextTypeHtmlTests.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Users\marti\Source\Repos\martin-honnen\MauiLabelTextTypeHtmlTests\bin\Debug\net7.0-windows10.0.19041.0\win10-x64\AppX\System.Linq.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'MauiLabelTextTypeHtmlTests.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Users\marti\Source\Repos\martin-honnen\MauiLabelTextTypeHtmlTests\bin\Debug\net7.0-windows10.0.19041.0\win10-x64\AppX\Microsoft.InteractiveExperiences.Projection.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'MauiLabelTextTypeHtmlTests.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Users\marti\Source\Repos\martin-honnen\MauiLabelTextTypeHtmlTests\bin\Debug\net7.0-windows10.0.19041.0\win10-x64\AppX\Microsoft.Maui.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'MauiLabelTextTypeHtmlTests.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Users\marti\Source\Repos\martin-honnen\MauiLabelTextTypeHtmlTests\bin\Debug\net7.0-windows10.0.19041.0\win10-x64\AppX\Microsoft.Maui.Controls.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'MauiLabelTextTypeHtmlTests.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Users\marti\Source\Repos\martin-honnen\MauiLabelTextTypeHtmlTests\bin\Debug\net7.0-windows10.0.19041.0\win10-x64\AppX\Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'MauiLabelTextTypeHtmlTests.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Users\marti\Source\Repos\martin-honnen\MauiLabelTextTypeHtmlTests\bin\Debug\net7.0-windows10.0.19041.0\win10-x64\AppX\Microsoft.Maui.Essentials.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'MauiLabelTextTypeHtmlTests.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Users\marti\Source\Repos\martin-honnen\MauiLabelTextTypeHtmlTests\bin\Debug\net7.0-windows10.0.19041.0\win10-x64\AppX\Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Xaml.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'MauiLabelTextTypeHtmlTests.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Users\marti\Source\Repos\martin-honnen\MauiLabelTextTypeHtmlTests\bin\Debug\net7.0-windows10.0.19041.0\win10-x64\AppX\Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'MauiLabelTextTypeHtmlTests.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Users\marti\Source\Repos\martin-honnen\MauiLabelTextTypeHtmlTests\bin\Debug\net7.0-windows10.0.19041.0\win10-x64\AppX\Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'MauiLabelTextTypeHtmlTests.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Users\marti\Source\Repos\martin-honnen\MauiLabelTextTypeHtmlTests\bin\Debug\net7.0-windows10.0.19041.0\win10-x64\AppX\Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'MauiLabelTextTypeHtmlTests.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Users\marti\Source\Repos\martin-honnen\MauiLabelTextTypeHtmlTests\bin\Debug\net7.0-windows10.0.19041.0\win10-x64\AppX\Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Abstractions.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'MauiLabelTextTypeHtmlTests.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Users\marti\Source\Repos\martin-honnen\MauiLabelTextTypeHtmlTests\bin\Debug\net7.0-windows10.0.19041.0\win10-x64\AppX\Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'MauiLabelTextTypeHtmlTests.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Users\marti\Source\Repos\martin-honnen\MauiLabelTextTypeHtmlTests\bin\Debug\net7.0-windows10.0.19041.0\win10-x64\AppX\System.Xml.ReaderWriter.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'MauiLabelTextTypeHtmlTests.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Users\marti\Source\Repos\martin-honnen\MauiLabelTextTypeHtmlTests\bin\Debug\net7.0-windows10.0.19041.0\win10-x64\AppX\System.Private.Xml.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'MauiLabelTextTypeHtmlTests.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Users\marti\Source\Repos\martin-honnen\MauiLabelTextTypeHtmlTests\bin\Debug\net7.0-windows10.0.19041.0\win10-x64\AppX\Microsoft.Maui.Graphics.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'MauiLabelTextTypeHtmlTests.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Users\marti\Source\Repos\martin-honnen\MauiLabelTextTypeHtmlTests\bin\Debug\net7.0-windows10.0.19041.0\win10-x64\AppX\System.Net.Primitives.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'MauiLabelTextTypeHtmlTests.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Users\marti\Source\Repos\martin-honnen\MauiLabelTextTypeHtmlTests\bin\Debug\net7.0-windows10.0.19041.0\win10-x64\AppX\Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'MauiLabelTextTypeHtmlTests.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Users\marti\Source\Repos\martin-honnen\MauiLabelTextTypeHtmlTests\bin\Debug\net7.0-windows10.0.19041.0\win10-x64\AppX\System.ComponentModel.TypeConverter.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'MauiLabelTextTypeHtmlTests.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Users\marti\Source\Repos\martin-honnen\MauiLabelTextTypeHtmlTests\bin\Debug\net7.0-windows10.0.19041.0\win10-x64\AppX\Microsoft.Maui.Graphics.Win2D.WinUI.Desktop.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'MauiLabelTextTypeHtmlTests.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Users\marti\Source\Repos\martin-honnen\MauiLabelTextTypeHtmlTests\bin\Debug\net7.0-windows10.0.19041.0\win10-x64\AppX\Microsoft.Extensions.Options.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'MauiLabelTextTypeHtmlTests.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Users\marti\Source\Repos\martin-honnen\MauiLabelTextTypeHtmlTests\bin\Debug\net7.0-windows10.0.19041.0\win10-x64\AppX\Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'MauiLabelTextTypeHtmlTests.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Users\marti\Source\Repos\martin-honnen\MauiLabelTextTypeHtmlTests\bin\Debug\net7.0-windows10.0.19041.0\win10-x64\AppX\System.Diagnostics.Tracing.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'MauiLabelTextTypeHtmlTests.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Users\marti\Source\Repos\martin-honnen\MauiLabelTextTypeHtmlTests\bin\Debug\net7.0-windows10.0.19041.0\win10-x64\AppX\System.Threading.ThreadPool.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'MauiLabelTextTypeHtmlTests.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Users\marti\Source\Repos\martin-honnen\MauiLabelTextTypeHtmlTests\bin\Debug\net7.0-windows10.0.19041.0\win10-x64\AppX\System.Memory.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'MauiLabelTextTypeHtmlTests.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Users\marti\Source\Repos\martin-honnen\MauiLabelTextTypeHtmlTests\bin\Debug\net7.0-windows10.0.19041.0\win10-x64\AppX\System.Linq.Expressions.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'MauiLabelTextTypeHtmlTests.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Users\marti\Source\Repos\martin-honnen\MauiLabelTextTypeHtmlTests\bin\Debug\net7.0-windows10.0.19041.0\win10-x64\AppX\System.Reflection.Emit.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'MauiLabelTextTypeHtmlTests.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'Snippets'. 
'MauiLabelTextTypeHtmlTests.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Users\marti\Source\Repos\martin-honnen\MauiLabelTextTypeHtmlTests\bin\Debug\net7.0-windows10.0.19041.0\win10-x64\AppX\Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Compatibility.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'MauiLabelTextTypeHtmlTests.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Users\marti\Source\Repos\martin-honnen\MauiLabelTextTypeHtmlTests\bin\Debug\net7.0-windows10.0.19041.0\win10-x64\AppX\System.Reflection.Emit.Lightweight.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'MauiLabelTextTypeHtmlTests.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Users\marti\Source\Repos\martin-honnen\MauiLabelTextTypeHtmlTests\bin\Debug\net7.0-windows10.0.19041.0\win10-x64\AppX\System.Reflection.Emit.ILGeneration.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'MauiLabelTextTypeHtmlTests.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Users\marti\Source\Repos\martin-honnen\MauiLabelTextTypeHtmlTests\bin\Debug\net7.0-windows10.0.19041.0\win10-x64\AppX\System.Reflection.Primitives.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'MauiLabelTextTypeHtmlTests.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Users\marti\Source\Repos\martin-honnen\MauiLabelTextTypeHtmlTests\bin\Debug\net7.0-windows10.0.19041.0\win10-x64\AppX\System.Runtime.Loader.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'MauiLabelTextTypeHtmlTests.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Users\marti\Source\Repos\martin-honnen\MauiLabelTextTypeHtmlTests\bin\Debug\net7.0-windows10.0.19041.0\win10-x64\AppX\System.Text.RegularExpressions.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'MauiLabelTextTypeHtmlTests.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Users\marti\Source\Repos\martin-honnen\MauiLabelTextTypeHtmlTests\bin\Debug\net7.0-windows10.0.19041.0\win10-x64\AppX\System.Xml.XDocument.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'MauiLabelTextTypeHtmlTests.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Users\marti\Source\Repos\martin-honnen\MauiLabelTextTypeHtmlTests\bin\Debug\net7.0-windows10.0.19041.0\win10-x64\AppX\System.Private.Xml.Linq.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'MauiLabelTextTypeHtmlTests.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Users\marti\Source\Repos\martin-honnen\MauiLabelTextTypeHtmlTests\bin\Debug\net7.0-windows10.0.19041.0\win10-x64\AppX\System.Threading.Thread.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'MauiLabelTextTypeHtmlTests.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Users\marti\Source\Repos\martin-honnen\MauiLabelTextTypeHtmlTests\bin\Debug\net7.0-windows10.0.19041.0\win10-x64\AppX\System.Diagnostics.StackTrace.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'MauiLabelTextTypeHtmlTests.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Users\marti\Source\Repos\martin-honnen\MauiLabelTextTypeHtmlTests\bin\Debug\net7.0-windows10.0.19041.0\win10-x64\AppX\System.Reflection.Metadata.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'MauiLabelTextTypeHtmlTests.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Users\marti\Source\Repos\martin-honnen\MauiLabelTextTypeHtmlTests\bin\Debug\net7.0-windows10.0.19041.0\win10-x64\AppX\System.Collections.Immutable.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
The program '[33576] MauiLabelTextTypeHtmlTests.exe' has exited with code 0 (0x0).
```

The debug output pane for e.g. the Label `<Label TextType="Html"><![CDATA[<p>This is line 1.<br>This is line 2.<br>This is line 3.</p>]]></Label>` shows the following:

```
'MauiLabelTextTypeHtmlTests.exe' (CoreCLR: DefaultDomain): Loaded 'C:\Users\marti\Source\Repos\martin-honnen\MauiLabelTextTypeHtmlTests\bin\Debug\net7.0-windows10.0.19041.0\win10-x64\AppX\System.Private.CoreLib.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'MauiLabelTextTypeHtmlTests.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Users\marti\Source\Repos\martin-honnen\MauiLabelTextTypeHtmlTests\bin\Debug\net7.0-windows10.0.19041.0\win10-x64\AppX\MauiLabelTextTypeHtmlTests.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'MauiLabelTextTypeHtmlTests.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Users\marti\Source\Repos\martin-honnen\MauiLabelTextTypeHtmlTests\bin\Debug\net7.0-windows10.0.19041.0\win10-x64\AppX\System.Runtime.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'MauiLabelTextTypeHtmlTests.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Users\marti\Source\Repos\martin-honnen\MauiLabelTextTypeHtmlTests\bin\Debug\net7.0-windows10.0.19041.0\win10-x64\AppX\WinRT.Runtime.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'MauiLabelTextTypeHtmlTests.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Users\marti\Source\Repos\martin-honnen\MauiLabelTextTypeHtmlTests\bin\Debug\net7.0-windows10.0.19041.0\win10-x64\AppX\System.Runtime.InteropServices.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'MauiLabelTextTypeHtmlTests.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Users\marti\Source\Repos\martin-honnen\MauiLabelTextTypeHtmlTests\bin\Debug\net7.0-windows10.0.19041.0\win10-x64\AppX\System.Collections.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'MauiLabelTextTypeHtmlTests.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Users\marti\Source\Repos\martin-honnen\MauiLabelTextTypeHtmlTests\bin\Debug\net7.0-windows10.0.19041.0\win10-x64\AppX\System.Collections.Concurrent.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'MauiLabelTextTypeHtmlTests.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Users\marti\Source\Repos\martin-honnen\MauiLabelTextTypeHtmlTests\bin\Debug\net7.0-windows10.0.19041.0\win10-x64\AppX\System.Threading.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'MauiLabelTextTypeHtmlTests.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Users\marti\Source\Repos\martin-honnen\MauiLabelTextTypeHtmlTests\bin\Debug\net7.0-windows10.0.19041.0\win10-x64\AppX\Microsoft.WinUI.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'MauiLabelTextTypeHtmlTests.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Users\marti\Source\Repos\martin-honnen\MauiLabelTextTypeHtmlTests\bin\Debug\net7.0-windows10.0.19041.0\win10-x64\AppX\System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'MauiLabelTextTypeHtmlTests.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Users\marti\Source\Repos\martin-honnen\MauiLabelTextTypeHtmlTests\bin\Debug\net7.0-windows10.0.19041.0\win10-x64\AppX\System.Private.Uri.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'MauiLabelTextTypeHtmlTests.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Users\marti\Source\Repos\martin-honnen\MauiLabelTextTypeHtmlTests\bin\Debug\net7.0-windows10.0.19041.0\win10-x64\AppX\System.ObjectModel.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'MauiLabelTextTypeHtmlTests.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Users\marti\Source\Repos\martin-honnen\MauiLabelTextTypeHtmlTests\bin\Debug\net7.0-windows10.0.19041.0\win10-x64\AppX\System.ComponentModel.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'MauiLabelTextTypeHtmlTests.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Users\marti\Source\Repos\martin-honnen\MauiLabelTextTypeHtmlTests\bin\Debug\net7.0-windows10.0.19041.0\win10-x64\AppX\System.Numerics.Vectors.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'MauiLabelTextTypeHtmlTests.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Users\marti\Source\Repos\martin-honnen\MauiLabelTextTypeHtmlTests\bin\Debug\net7.0-windows10.0.19041.0\win10-x64\AppX\Microsoft.Windows.SDK.NET.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'MauiLabelTextTypeHtmlTests.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Users\marti\Source\Repos\martin-honnen\MauiLabelTextTypeHtmlTests\bin\Debug\net7.0-windows10.0.19041.0\win10-x64\AppX\System.Security.Cryptography.Algorithms.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'MauiLabelTextTypeHtmlTests.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Users\marti\Source\Repos\martin-honnen\MauiLabelTextTypeHtmlTests\bin\Debug\net7.0-windows10.0.19041.0\win10-x64\AppX\System.Security.Cryptography.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'MauiLabelTextTypeHtmlTests.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Users\marti\Source\Repos\martin-honnen\MauiLabelTextTypeHtmlTests\bin\Debug\net7.0-windows10.0.19041.0\win10-x64\AppX\System.Security.Cryptography.Csp.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'MauiLabelTextTypeHtmlTests.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Users\marti\Source\Repos\martin-honnen\MauiLabelTextTypeHtmlTests\bin\Debug\net7.0-windows10.0.19041.0\win10-x64\AppX\System.Security.Cryptography.Primitives.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'MauiLabelTextTypeHtmlTests.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Users\marti\Source\Repos\martin-honnen\MauiLabelTextTypeHtmlTests\bin\Debug\net7.0-windows10.0.19041.0\win10-x64\AppX\System.Linq.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'MauiLabelTextTypeHtmlTests.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Users\marti\Source\Repos\martin-honnen\MauiLabelTextTypeHtmlTests\bin\Debug\net7.0-windows10.0.19041.0\win10-x64\AppX\Microsoft.InteractiveExperiences.Projection.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'MauiLabelTextTypeHtmlTests.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Users\marti\Source\Repos\martin-honnen\MauiLabelTextTypeHtmlTests\bin\Debug\net7.0-windows10.0.19041.0\win10-x64\AppX\Microsoft.Maui.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'MauiLabelTextTypeHtmlTests.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Users\marti\Source\Repos\martin-honnen\MauiLabelTextTypeHtmlTests\bin\Debug\net7.0-windows10.0.19041.0\win10-x64\AppX\Microsoft.Maui.Controls.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'MauiLabelTextTypeHtmlTests.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Users\marti\Source\Repos\martin-honnen\MauiLabelTextTypeHtmlTests\bin\Debug\net7.0-windows10.0.19041.0\win10-x64\AppX\Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'MauiLabelTextTypeHtmlTests.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Users\marti\Source\Repos\martin-honnen\MauiLabelTextTypeHtmlTests\bin\Debug\net7.0-windows10.0.19041.0\win10-x64\AppX\Microsoft.Maui.Essentials.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'MauiLabelTextTypeHtmlTests.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Users\marti\Source\Repos\martin-honnen\MauiLabelTextTypeHtmlTests\bin\Debug\net7.0-windows10.0.19041.0\win10-x64\AppX\Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Xaml.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'MauiLabelTextTypeHtmlTests.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Users\marti\Source\Repos\martin-honnen\MauiLabelTextTypeHtmlTests\bin\Debug\net7.0-windows10.0.19041.0\win10-x64\AppX\Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'MauiLabelTextTypeHtmlTests.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Users\marti\Source\Repos\martin-honnen\MauiLabelTextTypeHtmlTests\bin\Debug\net7.0-windows10.0.19041.0\win10-x64\AppX\Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'MauiLabelTextTypeHtmlTests.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Users\marti\Source\Repos\martin-honnen\MauiLabelTextTypeHtmlTests\bin\Debug\net7.0-windows10.0.19041.0\win10-x64\AppX\Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
```

Comment: `<Label TextType="Html"><![CDATA[<p>This is paragraph 1.</p><p>This is paragraph 2.</p>]]></Label>` indeed renders fine under Windows. But is anyone in 2022 really throwing an XML parser at something labelled as HTML?

Comment: `<Label TextType="Html"><![CDATA[<p>This is line 1.<br>This is line 2.<br>This is line 3.</p>]]></Label>` renders on both Windows and Android so at least it is probably not a failed XML parsing attempt that makes the example from the question fail under Windows.

Comment: What exception causes the crash?  Have you looked at MAUI source to see what might be happening?

Comment: Even in VS Studio I don't see a clear exception, the app window just vanishes (or doesn't even show up). I am not familiar with the MAUI code base and have not managed to identify where/how platform dependent code is stored/kept, https://github.com/dotnet/maui/blob/main/src/Controls/src/Core/Label.cs doesn't seem to indicate what is happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I have found the relevant code in https://github.com/dotnet/maui/blob/17790124c566d73001761ea93a447876e4ed0b90/src/Core/src/Platform/Windows/TextBlockExtensions.cs#L101, it first seems to wrap the HTML fragment text into a `div` element with e.g. `var modifiedText = string.Format("<div>{0}</div>", text);`, then indeed does some cosmetic regular expression replacement to be able to deal with HTML `<br>` tag syntax in `modifiedText = Regex.Replace(modifiedText, "<br>", "<br></br>", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);` (which explains why my `br` sample worked) and finally indeed throws the modified HTML at an XML parser with e.g. `var element = XElement.Parse(modifiedText);`.

So for some strange reasons in 2022 with HTML5 and text/html being the established parsing approach for HTML for more than a decade, MAUI under Windows thinks an XML parser is adequate for HTML parsing.

Still need to figure why nothing is rendered and the app crashes/does not appear/disappears (depending on when/where you set your HTML text) as the code at least seems to want to fall back on some normal rendering of text with e.g.

```
        try
        {
            var element = XElement.Parse(modifiedText);
            LabelHtmlHelper.ParseText(element, platformControl.Inlines, label);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            // If anything goes wrong just show the html
            platformControl.Text = global::Windows.Data.Html.HtmlUtilities.ConvertToText(label.Text);
        }
```